# Write the difference between 2 CSVs to a new CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Compare data of a column in two CSV files, in this example, the first column. If found new data, write the entire row to the new CSV. I will only be using first column as primary key between two CSV files to manipulate.

```
f1.csv

a,adata,adata2
b,bdata,bdata2
c,cdata,cdata2

f2.csv

a,adata,adata2
b,bdata,bdata2
c,cdata,cdata2
d,ddata,ddata2
e,edata,edata2
f,fdata,fdata2

Output:

f3.csv

d,ddata,ddata2
e,edata,edata2
f,fdata,fdata2
```

*Code*:

```py
for row1 in reader1:
    data = row1[0]
    for row2 in reader2:
        if data == row2[0]:
            print("eq")
        else :
            print("different")
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! what exactly is your question? please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). what does not work in the program you wrote? where are you stuck? what is the desired output? what is the output you are getting?

Comment: it might also help to know if the input files are always sorted by the key (as they are in your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files are unordered, you will have to read the keys of the entire first file into memory first, then you can check if there are new keys in the second file.

```
keys = set()
for row in reader1:
    keys.add(row[0])

for row in reader2:
    if row[0] not in keys:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If it's sorted you can do something more clever, but this is unclear.

Comment: The logic worked like a charm...... Thanks bro. I will the update the full script after few changes.